# Echoed time differs from time saved in DB: all minutes are the same

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone, timestamp

I have an **EVENT table in my database**, and for each row there's a timestamp.

The date and **time showed in the DB is correct** (and being saved as America/Los Angeles).

When I try to show a list of those events on a page, the **echoed time is wrong.** for each of the rows.

ALL the **minutes show the number '10'** (7:10pm, 11:10pm, 3:10am, 8:10am) which is wrong.

**What could explain such a weird behavior ?**

In a nutshell:

```
       DB                           Output

 2013-10-21 16:16:01       Oct 21, 2013 - 04:10 pm
 2013-10-21 16:16:45       Oct 21, 2013 - 04:10 pm
 2013-10-21 19:38:07       Oct 21, 2013 - 07:10 pm
 2013-10-22 17:54:31       Oct 22, 2013 - 05:10 pm
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code please. We're not psychic.

Comment: @John Conde: Speak for yourself. `m` is for month not minute.  Use `i` for minute in the date() format.

Comment: LOL~ I do this all the time.

Comment: You need to show the PHP where you output the date

Comment: I edited my answer. But @AbraCadaver just solved my issue !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
date('M j Y h:i a')
```

Not:

```
date('M j Y h:m a')
```

m is month and i is minute

Comment: Wow.  That is an amazing catch given that problem statement.

Comment: Well, when you've made this mistake as often as I have it just sticks out :-)  All  the times are 10 for the minutes, Oct is the 10th month...